# how to find index with rindex in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter

I have the following array

```
"testArr": [
  {
    "start": "2020-10-9",
    "dest": "2020-10-10"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-10-10",
    "dest": null
  },
  {
    "start": null,
    "dest": null
  }
]
```

I want get index of the element whose start is not null but dest is null. Something like this below:

```
index = testArr.rindex{|x| x.start.nil? && x.dest.nil?}

puts index
```

But I keep getting syntax error. I am new to ruby. Could anyone pls help ?

Thanks

Comment: _"I have the following array ... I keep getting syntax error"_ – well, that's not valid Ruby code. It looks more like a JSON snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `testArr` is `Array of Hashes` you have to access value of hash key like `hash[key]` & not like `hash.key` i.e. `x[:start]` instead of `x.start`

Following should work

```
index = testArr.rindex {|x| x[:start].present? && x[:dest].nil?}
```

Check following

```
[4] pry(main)> testArr = [ {"start": "2020-10-9", "dest": "2020-10-10" }, {"start": "2020-10-10", "dest": nil}, {"start": nil, "dest": nil}]
=> [{:start=>"2020-10-9", :dest=>"2020-10-10"}, {:start=>"2020-10-10", :dest=>nil}, {:start=>nil, :dest=>nil}]
[5] pry(main)> testArr.rindex {|x| x[:start].present? && x[:dest].nil?}
=> 1
```